# What are Solidity Events

Tags: events, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

I have been struggling for quite some time with finding an explanation to what events are in Solidity (or in the Blockchain context). As far as I understand, they are a way of storing (or logging) information on the particular contract that can then be updated throughout the life of that contract. But how is this different than a plain ol' variable? Why can't I just create a variable that is then simply updated with new information?

Comment: Here is an earlier Q&A https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/12950/what-are-solidity-events-and-how-they-are-related-to-topics-and-logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/contracts.html#events):

> *Solidity events give an abstraction on top of the EVM’s logging functionality. Applications can subscribe and listen to these events through the RPC interface of an Ethereum client.*

It's easier for an off-chain app to subscribe to new event logs than to a variable change. Especially when the variable is not `public`.

Same goes for querying historical event logs (easy through the JSON-RPC API and its wrappers such as Web3 or Ethers.js), vs. historical changes of the variable (complicated, would need to query a node for each block and look for the changes proactively).

Example: The [ERC-20](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20.md) token standard defines the `Transfer()` event. A token contract emits this event each time a transfer (of its tokens) occurs. This allows a blockchain explorer (or any other off-chain app) to react to this event - for example to update their own database of token holders. Without the event, they would have no way (or a very complicated way at least) to learn about the transfer.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you for explaining this. Highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

- Events in Solidity can be used to log certain events in EVM logs. These are useful when clients are required to be notified of any change or event in the contract. Or maybe in the future you need to search for something that has happened so you go through all the logs. These logs are stored on the blockchain in `transaction logs`. Logs cannot be accessed from the contracts but are used as a mechanism to notify change of state or the occurrence of an event in the contract. They help us write asynchronous applications.
- Events are stored in the `logsBloom` which is in the header of each block.
- Events are piece of data executed on the blockchain and stored in the blockchain but not accessible by any smart contracts. it is kinda `console.log` in javascript or `print` in python.
- Events are much more gas efficient than using a storage variable
- Events are useful for testing the contract. If you interact with oracles, you sometimes want to see if the function call by oracle service is done or not. To see if the function call is done, you emit the result of the function or one of the properties of the result.
- Events are useful if you want to maintain the history/log of every change that happens in a mapping.
- Deposit contracts were created on the Ethereum 1.0 chain. This kind of smart contract is used for depositing ETH on the beacon chain. An event is emitted every time a deposit is made.
- There are two events that must be present in an ERC-20-compliant token:

  - Transfer : This event must trigger when tokens are transferred, including any zero-value transfers. The event is defined as follows:

  ```
  event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value)
  ```

  - Approval : This event must trigger when a successful call is made to the approve function.

  ```
  event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value)
  ```

You can read this article for deep dive: [transaction-receipt-trie-and-logs-simplified](https://medium.com/coinmonks/ethereum-data-transaction-receipt-trie-and-logs-simplified-30e3ae8dc3cf)

Comment: Can we have more than 1 emit per function? If so, does "emit Transfer()" have be the last one if it's one of the 2? Thanks!

Comment: @Vincent you can emit multiple events in a function but it wont make sense because when we write functions we want to make sure each function does only one thing. also events will cost gas.

Comment: But what if I need to create a log that I want to access from a dapp? Currently I have this in TransferFrom(): ... emit EventLogs(sender, recipient, 'success', amountReceived, block.timestamp);
emit Transfer(sender, recipient, amountReceived); But it doesn't seem to be working. Can I just remove the "emit Transfer"?

Comment: @Vincent  you better ask a question on stackoverflow with enough information and details and debugging information.

Answer (score 0):

Solidity events are pieces of data that are emitted and stored in the blockchain. When you emit an event it creates a log that front-end applications can use to trigger changes in the UI.

It's a cheap form of storage.

You can define an event like this:

```
event Message(address indexed sender, address indexed recipient, string message);
```

and emit an event like this:

```
emit Message(msg.sender, _recipient, "Hello World!");
```