# How can I monitor when a smart contract function gets called? Preferably using ethers.js or web3.js

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I have a few instances where I want to monitor smart contract function calls, but I'm not totally sure how to go about doing that. I've read through the ethers.js and web3.js docs but haven't figured anything out yet.

For example, Etherscan shows methods such as 'transfer', 'approve', 'mint', etc for every transaction that corresponds to a function call. How can I monitor a specific contract for when a certain contract is called?

Answer (score 1):

You should write an event. For example:

```
event Transfer(
        address indexed _from,
        address indexed _to,
        uint _value
    );
```

then in transfer function call it:

```
function transfer(address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool success){
        // run some logic
        // if you reached here, means everyting went ok
        emit Transfer(msg.sender,_to,_value);
        return true;
    }
```

For more, read [What are Solidity Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69112487/what-are-solidity-events)

Comment: I’m wanting to monitor functions calls for contracts that aren’t my own, and for the most part, don’t emit events. Does this help clarify more so what I’m trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can use the txn receipt data on testnet and txn trace data (e.g alchemy provides an API to access this) to monitor smart contract function calls without events.

This might be a helpful read:
https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/how-does-defender-listens-to-function-calls-on-smart-contracts/30446